# Is it possible to know whether audio is currently being played on pc (windows) in C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, audio

I want to create a listener that should return true or false based on whether audio (from the browser or Spotify etc.) is currently being played, preferably written in C. However, I'm willing to change the language if needed. I was wondering if you guys know of any API that would make this possible.

I couldn't find anything on Google. I also tried doing this in Python, but I could only get the program to check for microphone input using WIN32, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Anything that tells whether whether some audio is currently being emitted on the system can have a different answer in the next nanosecond, so any such API would be useless.

Comment: @PaulDempsey This isn't true. I can totally see a feasibility and usefulness of something like `AudioDeviceIsBusy()` call, and I am pretty sure something like this exists in the WinAPI.

Comment: You can use something like IAudioMeterInformation from Core Audio APIs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nn-endpointvolume-iaudiometerinformation?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I fail to come up with a practical use case for a proposed `AudioDeviceIsBusy` function. The only time you actually do care about whether any given resource is available is when you intend to use it. And in that case, you request access, and handle potential errors. What would be a useful use case where this pattern won't work?

Comment: @IInspectable For example a simple UI indicator showing the audio device is in use

Comment: @EugeneSh. The UI may be simple, but the underlying problem isn't nearly *that* simple. What does *"is in use"* mean? And why would it be useful to see that *some* resources of an audio device are in use? There is no `AudioDeviceIsBusy` system API, because that is an oversimplification. The audio device may still be able to service additional resource requests, or it may not, so having this information is rather meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `IAudioMeterInformation` from the windows core audio api, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IMMDeviceEnumerator *dev_enumerator;
    IMMDevice *dev;
    IAudioMeterInformation *audio_meter;

    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), 
                     NULL, 
                     CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                     __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
                     (void**)&dev_enumerator);

    dev_enumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender,
                                            eConsole, 
                                            &dev);

    dev->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioMeterInformation),
                  CLSCTX_ALL, 
                  NULL,
                  (void**)&audio_meter);

    while(1){
        float peak;
        audio_meter->GetPeakValue(&peak);
        printf("%f\n", peak);
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

That gives you the normalized peak volume of the default audio device.
Note: All error handling was ommitted in the program above.

Comment: Check the restrictions and limitations of this interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nn-endpointvolume-iaudiometerinformation -- you may have trouble if something else has the device in exclusive mode, or the device doesn't have a hardware peak level meter.