Python: determine whether the microphone is turned on in Windows
How can I use python to find out if the microphone is on on a Windows system? All I found was a single question Python check if microphone input is muted to which there is simply no answer!
All I have is code that just switches the microphone state:
import win32api
import win32gui


win32api.SendMessage(
    win32gui.GetForegroundWindow(), 0x319, None, 0x180000
)


You can't really know that, but you can get the current audio volume using this type of python code in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112457/python-change-windows-7-master-volume with the IAudioMeterInformation interface and GetPeakValue method instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudiometerinformation-getpeakvalue like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158386/is-it-possible-to-know-whether-audio-is-currently-being-played-on-pc-windows-i

@SimonMourier, the links you provided have nothing to do with the question asked..
